# How to convert exe to elf

Tags: javascript, exe, elf, node-webkit, playstation

I made a game using JavaScript. I converted it to exe using  [NW.JS](https://nwjs.io/), but I want to run the game on Playstation. I found out from the Internet that you need .ELF files to run it on console. I want to know how to convert .exe to.elf.

Comment: Playstation 4 is the one I am talking about

Answer (score 3):

You can't.

There is more platform-specificness to a piece of software than just the type of binary file it ends up in.

If you want to run it on the console you'll need to use a framework that supports that kind of console in the first place.